# Using formula as parameter in LOADRunner

Tags: loadrunner

I wish to create a customer hierarchy which has data something like the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XojNP.png)
{{ one main customer, having 2 customers beneath, and then there is 50 accounts associated at the last leaf node)
This is one customer hierarchy. Likewise I have to create 500 Customer hierarchy.
The naming convention is to maintained in same way as shown in picture.
500_50_001  is common in all names used in pic .
So when we create similar data set 500 times we only tweak last 3 digits like below.
For Customer1: 500_50_001  (here 001 means customer hierarchy 1)
For customer2: 500_50_002
For Customer3: 500_50_003

This is achievable for me by creating CSV file . but that would mean to create 500 such similar data set ,as one single name cannot be repeated.
Please guide how can I achieve this in loadrunner.

Answer (score 2):

Loops+sprintf()+formatting conventions for number of digits + standard C file IO for output.

I will not write this for you as the likelihood is high that this is a pre-employment screen to check for C programming skills